# Sinon.js spy.called not working on RPCs

Tags: javascript, mocha.js, sinon, crossbar, autobahnjs

### Background

I have a server that registers some RPCs using crossbar, and a test that is trying to make sure that the RPCs are being called using sinon.

### Code

**server.js**

```
"use strict";

const autobahn = require( "autobahn" );


const server = () => {

    const open = () => console.log( "Hello world" );

    const start = () => new Promise( fulfil => {

        const connection = new autobahn.Connection( {
            "url": "ws://localhost:8080/ws",
            "realm": "realm1"
        } );

        connection.onopen = session => {
            session.register( "server.open", open )
                .then(() => fulfil())
                .catch(console.log);
        };

        connection.open();
    } );

    //removing Object.freeze won't help =(
    return Object.freeze({
        start,
        open
    });
};

module.exports = server;
```

This server simply connects to the crossbar and then registers the `open` RPC.

Now my test case. I am using mocha with chai:

**test.js**

```
"use strict";

const expect = require( "chai" )
    .expect;
const autobahn = require( "autobahn" );
const sinon = require( "sinon" );
const serverFactory = require( "./server.js" );

describe( "server", () => {

    const server = serverFactory();

    const crossbar = {
        connection: undefined,
        session: undefined
    };

    const connectToCrossbar = () => new Promise( fulfil => {

        crossbar.connection = new autobahn.Connection({
            "url": "ws://localhost:8080/ws",
            "realm": "realm1"
        });

        crossbar.connection.onopen = session => {
            crossbar.session = session;
            fulfil(); 
        };

        crossbar.connection.open();
    } );


    before( "start server", done => {
        server.start()
            .then( connectToCrossbar )
            .then( done )
            .catch( err => done( err ) );
    } );

    it( "should open", done => {
        const openSpy = sinon.spy( server, "open" );

        crossbar.session.call( "server.open", [] )
            .then( () => {
                expect( openSpy.called ).to.be.true;
                done();
            } )
            .catch( err => done( err ) );
    } );

} );
```

This test opens a connection to the crossbar as well and then calls the `open` method on the server.

### Problem

The problem is that even though I see the `Hello World` console.log, proving that the method was in fact executed, my test always fails because of the  `openSpy.called` is always `false` (even though the spied method was called!).

### What I tried

1. Removing `Object.freeze`. I understand spies and stubs actually replace the functions and objects they are spying on, but in this case, it didn't help.
2. Using a `stub` instead of a `spy`. When my spy didn't work, I tried replacing the `open` method with a `stub` and use the `callsFake` to finish the test. Unfortunately `callsFake` never seems to be called ...
3. Using `setTimeout`. I thought that perhaps the reason this was happening was that I am making the test to soon, so I created a  `setTimeout` with `0` evolving the `expect` statement. Also failed.

### Question

1. What am I doing wrong?
2. How can I fix it?

Comment: `const openSpy = sinon.spy( server, "open" );` is where it's hanging on. You're trying to spy on a `function` that is called `open` in the server, while there is no `function` that is called `open` in the server, which makes the `openSpy` always `false`.

Comment: Yes, there is: `const open = () => console.log( "Hello world" );`. And the console.log even prints!

Comment: The function is inside a function. Didn't see that, did you try calling to it using `const openSpy = sinon.spy( server, "server.open" );`?

Comment: I have tested it, it also fails =(

Comment: Have you also tried testing putting the `open` outside the `server` function or replacing the `hello world` with `return true`?

Comment: I tried the `open` function return true but it failed. Putting it outside my serverFactory would just defeat the purpose of the whole thing =(

Comment: I'm sorry :\ then I can't help either, but I'm very curious for the answer then +1 and following this

Comment: Thanks for the support!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### Disclaimer

This solution is built upon the testing and knowledge that I have with crossbar. If I am wrong, please feel free to correct me.

### My conclusion

Among many other problems `crossbar` has, one of them is the inability to do any kinds of tests. `autobahn`, being a library for `crossbar` shares these problems.

The reason my code doesn't work its because another process is actually calling my `open` function instead of my application. Thus the process running the test never knows that the function was called.

The solution for this, is to make the `open` function return a result, and then test if we receive the result:

```
it( "should be able to call registered RPCs", done => {
    server.getSession().call( "test1", [] )
        .then( response => {
            expect( response ).to.eql( "Hello World" );
            done();
        } )
        .catch( err => done( err ) );
} );
```

In reality using this middleware everything is harder to test ... but at least now I have a way!

Answer (score 0):

As per the Mocha docs on [testing Asynchronous code](https://mochajs.org/#asynchronous-code):

> By adding a callback (usually named done) to it(), Mocha will know that it should wait for this function to be called to complete the test.

You never call `done()` after the `expect()` call. Hence Mocha thinks your test is not yet done. This should solve your issue

```
it( "should open", done => {
    const openSpy = sinon.spy( server, "open" );

    crossbar.session.call( "server.open", [] )
        .then( () => {
            expect( openSpy.called ).to.be.true;
            done(); // You seem to have missed this statement here
        } )
        .catch( err => done( err ) );
} );
```

Comment: The problem is not that. I don't even get that far. The problem is that the assertion fails and it shouldn't!

Comment: Oh. Could you share the failure along with the stack trace? Also, did you try my solution?

Comment: It fails because it expected false to be true. Will try out as soon as I can!

Comment: Nope, nothing changes !

Comment: Alright. If you could share how I can set this up to do some debugging, maybe I can help.

Comment: all the code you need is in the question already :D All you have to do is copy paste it into a new project !